# When I am adding flashSection module in the app router, I can't route to /some/1 route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zydj.png)Only when I add @flashSection module inside the app router, I can't access the /some/1 page, when I remove the @flashSection module I can access that page, why is that happening to me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6dIL.png)

I want to have both of this folders in my router, I have tried with both of them but it doesn't works, can anyone explain to me how to solve this and why is that happening.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9RMk.png)

Answer (score 0):

While I may not be the best for this, I will try.

Maybe the flash section folder is overriding the code you have showed us. Personally, I would recommend that you show us the code in 'flash-section', so we can figure out whats going on.

Comment: Additionally, you are on the some/2 page btw

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because your url should be:

```
http://localhost:300/some/[id]/page
```

If you want to avoid writting the `page` word, I think your file `page.js` should be renamed to `index.js`